# Jave: trouble with my shallow copy constructor

Tags: java, constructor, copy, shallow-copy

I have trouble with my java homework.
I am making a Matrice class and i have trouble with the shallow constructor that take another Matrice as argument.

```
Public class Matrice implements IMatrice{

private static int numLignes ;
private static int numColonnes ;
private static ArrayList<Double> elements  ;

public Matrice(int numLignes, int numColonnes ) {
        this.numColonnes = numColonnes ;
        this.numLignes = numLignes ;

}

public Matrice(int numLignes, int numColonnes , double valeurs ){
    this(numLignes,numColonnes);
    this.elements = new ArrayList<>(numLignes * numColonnes);
    for(int i = 0 ;i< numLignes * numColonnes;i++){
        elements.add(valeurs);
    }




}

public Matrice(int numLignes, int numColonnes , double[] elements ) {
        this(numLignes,numColonnes);
        this.elements = new ArrayList<>() ;
        for(int i = 0 ;i<numLignes * numColonnes;i++){
            this.elements.add(elements[i]);

    }
}
public Matrice(Matrice autreMatrice) {
    numColonnes = autreMatrice.getNumColonnes();
    numLignes = autreMatrice.getNumLignes();

}
```

Is my shallow copy constructor is right ?
Because when i run my teacher main test, its say im wrong.
COuld be a error on my teacher main test, but i doubt it.

Thx !

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the other matrix content as well not only the dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

You could try doing this instead of getNumColonnes()

```
public Matrice(Matrice autreMatrice)
{
 autreMatrice.setNumColonnes(numColonnes);
 autreMatrice.setNumLignes(numLignes);
}
```

it should work if you have a setNumColonnes and setNumLines methods.

Comment: it is meant to be a copying constructor not a copy method.

Comment: sorry i misread the code in this way you just change your autreMatrice numColonnes and numLignes